# Understanding javascript closures and memory usage

Tags: javascript, closures

**EDIT**: This is just a simple example to demontrate the concern I have with a much larger program. I wouldn't use this actual code for anything :)

If I run this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function update(amount, win, data)
{
    win.innerText = 'Count is ' + amount;
    setTimeout(function() { update(amount + 1, win, {data: 'something'})}, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {

  var win = document.getElementById('item');    
  update(0, win, 0);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="item"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The call to setTimeout presumably creates a closure which captures the contents of the parameters to the "update" function (amount, win, data). So those variables are maintained in memory until the timeout is called and returns so that they will be available inside that function call...

But that function creates a *new* closure for the next iteration of the timeout... What will be captured in that second closure? Is it just the *new* copies of those variables or will the ones that formed part of the function call be captured *again* in the new closure?

Basically will this eventually run out of memory due to the data in each closure getting bigger and bigger, or is this safe and reasonable?

Comment: Essential reading: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my understanding, when a closure is created, the current lexical context is bundled with it. In your case, it would be the `amount, win, data`.

This context will be used, when the timeout fires, to execute the closure and thus call once again the function `update`; this call, although it might appear so, is not recursive, because the previous execution of `update` already ended and its original context (dynamic, which is different from the lexical one) has already been freed. (I think this is important to notice, because it seems you are worrying about a sort of stack growth due to recursion).

So, again, `update` is executed a second time and again a timeout is set and a closure created. This closure is bundled with the current lexical context of execution  (which still includes just `amount, win, data`) and scheduled with the timer. then `update` finishes and removed from the stack. then again the timer fires and update is called again...

So, you should not worry about an unlimited growth of the context, for two reasons: first, only the lexical context is bundled with the closure; the call is not actually recursive.

Comment: "only the lexical context is bundled with the closure" I guess that is the question I wanted to ask :) - And it's not the stack growth I was worried about, I know it's not recursive - it was the unlimited "capture" of data.

Answer (score 4):

A new closure is created every time the timeout callback is called, as you correctly say. But once the callback has been executed, there is no longer anything referencing the previous closure, so it can be garbage collected.

Comment: My concern is not over the first closure being garbage collected but over the data in the parameters passed in to the callback via the closure.... They are available when the 2nd closure is created so if they are captured in the *second* closure then they will not be freed. But I'm not sure if they will be or if it's only variable directly declared in that second function that are captured.